# bokeh - higher-level steps needed to present bokeh plot on personal website?

Tags: python, server, bokeh

This is my project: I want to automatically run a python script everyday that will pull and transform personal data (I have a SQL database that receives daily updates).  I want to then use Bokeh to publish an up-to-date, interactive visualization to a personal website (that I have yet to create).  I am a complete noob when it comes to website development so I am looking for higher-level guidance that will help me fill in the details more easily.

I was hoping that someone could explain to me, at a higher level, the steps I need to take to implement this plan.  I have a remote computer that is always connected to the internet and to the SQL database.  I was thinking:

1. On remote computer, set up ETL python script (run automatically every day with cron job)
2. On remote computer, write Bokeh code that creates wanted visualization based on data from step 1.
3. Set up personal website with web hosting service
4. ?

How do I push bokeh visualizations and the up-to-date (refreshed daily) data to the personal website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of different options, depending on whether you will be running your own server, or simply deploying static pages. If I understand your question, it sounds like you are just going to be deploying static files to a web host. In that there's a couple of options.

If you are content with the standard Bokeh HTML template:

- generate your plot with output_file and save()
- upload this .html file to your web host and link to it however you like
- re-generate and upload the resulting .html file to your web host periodically

If you want to embed a plot in a your own HTML with more control:

- Use bokeh.embed.autoload_static to create a my_plot.js file that has all the info for your plot. Docs here: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#autoload-scripts
- Upload my_plot.js to your host, and add appropriate reference to my_plot.js in your static HTML
- periodically re-run autoload_static to generate a new plot JS file, and upload it to your web host to replace the old version